# How can I get a single Theme for ICONS in 19.10

Tags: desktop-icons

After installing a clean 19.10 and setting icon themes, I get a mix of what I wanted, and the fat black ones on my desktop.
How can I control this.

A bypass is to switch the "ADWAITA" to "YARU"
It seems the ADWAITA icons are incomplete

[image: corner of desktop as a sample]

Comment: I think in your case.. Your icon theme does not have icons for the apps.. According to specs if the icon is not present in your custom chosen icon.. Then there is a mechanism to search for the icons in other themes

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/icon-theme-spec/